# Asp.net core hosted on Azure Functions with Azure Application insights - How to disable performance counter collection

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure function which is implemented using Asp.net core 2.2 which uses windows consumption plan. I am also using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package. I am trying to disable performance counter collection and I have been unsuccessful so far. Is there a way to disable perf counters collection?

The code that i am using to remove perf counters module is

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
  var serviceDescriptor = builder.Services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ImplementationType == typeof(PerformanceCollectorModule));
            builder.Services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
}
```

Still i am able to see perf counters in log analytics.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please paste the related code? and can you change your title to include the azure function?

Comment: Added code and resulting perf counter collection in log analytics @IvanYang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting `EnablePerformanceCountersCollection` which can be used to turn off perf counter collection. (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions.cs#L88)

This would go in host.json under applicationinsights

```
{
    "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 5
        },
         "EnablePerformanceCountersCollection" : false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hari Subramaniam,

I could think of defining empty counter like below, it will remove the perf counter( Doing programmatically, below is just an example):

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
    <DefaultCounters/>
    <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="Your Custom Counter"/>
    </Counters>
</Add>
```

Though in my opinion , instead of disabling it you can try to use the sampling which you can set it in the host.json.

Check this for additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#adaptive-sampling-telemetry-processor-from-200-beta3

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-counters

As per the code, if default initializer is true then it won't initialize other counter

```
if (!this.defaultCountersInitialized)
                        {
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time", @"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time Normalized", @"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time Normalized"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Memory\Available Bytes", @"\Memory\Available Bytes"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec", @"\ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\.NET CLR Exceptions(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\# of Exceps Thrown / sec", @"\.NET CLR Exceptions(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\# of Exceps Thrown / sec"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Request Execution Time", @"\ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Request Execution Time"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Private Bytes", @"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Private Bytes"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\IO Data Bytes/sec", @"\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\IO Data Bytes/sec"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests In Application Queue", @"\ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests In Application Queue"));
                            this.DefaultCounters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(@"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time", @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"));
                        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sampling is not applied to metrics, and hence sampling has no impact of performance counters.

Comment: @cijothomas, do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mohit verma. However, the config option of emptying out the counters, will that work with .net core apps? Not entirely sure if applicationinsights.config is meant to be used with .net core.

Comment: The suggestion made @cijothomas seems to work for my particular scenario

Comment: applicationinsights.config file is not supported in asp.net core apps (in Azure functions or otherwise)

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. @cijothomas Appreciate the response,